# How to implement scrollviewer bouncing's animation in c# and wpf?

Tags: c#, ios, wpf, scroll, scrollviewer

I want to implement scrollviewer bouncing's animation in c# and wpf, like IOS's UIScrollview.

When users scroll to top or end, it starts to decrease speed and bouncing.

I think that google can search related issues, but i can not find.

Does anyone have similar experiences?

Comment: "Someone" has got a patent on this in the US ;-) http://www.google.com/patents/US7469381

Answer (score 0):

Well for touch manipulation, WPF already has some built in support for this. Take a look at the [ReportBoundaryFeedback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988680.aspx) method and [ManipulationBoundaryFeedback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.manipulationboundaryfeedback.aspx) event. I believe the ScrollViewer automatically uses this when touch panning (see [PanningMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.panningmode.aspx)).